# Flashing Raspberry Pi CM V1.1 on a proprietary board

Tags: video, image, pi-1, compute-module

So I don't know much about Linux or the Raspberry Pi (Especially the compute module), But I've managed to obtain one that is using a custom/proprietary board alongside it.

All the thing is currently capable of doing is displaying ads that aren't of my choosing, and want to replace that with something like Puppy Linux.

I'm using a Windows 8.1 PC with the rpiboot.exe tool, trying to get it to boot correctly so I can install Puppy Linux onto it with something like Rufus, but it seems to refuse responding after answering with 4 bytes of data.

Some other online sources say to set one of the jumper pins (F6, I think it was?) to EN, but I don't know where that pin is on the board so I can't put it into USB slave mode to install the OS.

I can add pictures later, if need be; But for now, here's some basic info on the board itself to see if somebody can help me reprogram this board.

- Uses a NL-SW-LTE-TSVG Modem
- Has 2 USB ports: A USB 2.0 Type C and a USB 2.0 Type A
- Has a CMV1.1 connected
- Is currently connected to a functional Hydis screen, and some other speaker
- Does not have any other ports (That aren't pins) other than the 2 USBs
- Draws power from a 39.5Ah battery
- Has one set of four pins labled: DU, RX, TX, +3.3V (Power?)
- Has one set of 3 pins in 2 rows (One of them is power, restarts when touched)
- Made by Radiosmith 2016, model number 031-100-15

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

By "*proprietary Board*" I'm inferring that you mean an IO board from a third-party- one that doesn't ship with the default compute module kit.

I've flashed both the standard IO board that ships with the compute module as well as a third-party carrier board (IO Board) from Balena (which is *REALLY NICE!*)using the following procedure that I've previously documented here:

[How do I Flash (install) Raspbian on Raspberry Pi Compute Module 3 / 3+?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96032/how-do-i-flash-install-raspbian-on-raspberry-pi-compute-module-3-3)

The flashing Utility "*Etcher*" (which has a Windows version) will just see the compute module as a storage device and write any image (***it needn't be Raspbian***) to the Compute Module that you point *Etcher* to.

This should get you across the finish line with the minimal amount of effort and pain-

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the companion board is only designed for the part to act as a host (if it has two USB ports, there's likely a hub chip attached to the one CM USB port; the same problem with USB slave boot on the piB) so even if you did manage to find what routes to pin 2 on the module (physical pin 2, not GPIO 2) it wouldn't work; as everything upstream from it is expecting it to be the host.

Does the labeled Serial port work? (the RX and TX pins) because it likely gives additional info on boot, a shell, or both. Try hooking a USB to TTL serial converter to it (3.3v, anything higher will blow the pi).

If you really want to reprogram it, get a minimal CMIO board with a micro-USB port; then take it out of the system and insert it into the CMIO carrier. (that's likely how they programmed them in the first place)