# How do I Flash (install) Raspbian on Raspberry Pi Compute Module 3 / 3+?

Tags: raspbian, software-installation, image, compute-module-3, compute-module-development-kit

**NOTE: This question & solution ONLY relates to Compute Modules 3 or 3+ with on-board eMMC storage. The "*Lite*" versions of these has NO eMMC Storage**

I'm working on a project involving prototyping and bought a "***Raspberry Pi Compute Module 3 Dev Kit***" which shipped with a Compute Module 3 with 4GB of eMMC on-board storage and more recently the newer "***Raspberry Pi Compute Module 3+ Dev Kit***" with a Compute Module **3+** with 32GB of on-board eMMC storage.

Both kits ship with the "***Compute Module IO Board v3.0***" used to interface with these Compute Modules.

***How do I install Raspbian on the Compute Module's eMMC storage?!?!?!***

I'll share the (2) ways I found to populate the Compute Module 3/3+ eMMC storage with the Raspbian OS to hopefully make your lives considerably easier

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Method 1: Hard (Official) Way

Follow the official instructions from Raspberry Pi in below link if you like a ***Rube Goldberg*** / ***Heath Robinson*** way of doing things:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/computemodule/cm-emmc-flashing.md

### Method 2: Easy Way

Solution tested and known to work with Mac OSX version ***10.14.4*** on a ***Macbook Pro 2018***.  The adapters used with the legacy USB cable interface to connect to my Macbooks USB-C/Thunderbolt ports:

[Ailun Type C Adapter,USB C Adapter](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B01MYPX7Y8/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)

**Step 1: Download & install *Etcher* for your OS**

https://www.balena.io/etcher/

**Step 2: Configure Hardware Connections**

Insert a the MicroUSB end of the cable into the port labelled "***USB Slave***"and the other end into your computer's USB port.  Picture below shows USB-C adapter attached for users with only USB-C ports (new Macbooks).

**NOTE**: If **NOT** connecting to IO board with a USB-C lead (which supplies power to it) as pictured in example, connect power lead to board before proceeding.

[image: Connections]

My ***Compute Module IO Board*** (v3.0) shipped with the jumper correctly set, but ensure your "***USB Slave Boot Enable***" is set to "**EN**" and looks as below:

[image: Enable USB Slave Boot Jumper]

**Step 3: Flash eMMC Storage with Raspbian Image**

Start Etcher and then:

**Set the Source: Choose Raspbian Image to be installed on Compute Module**
Chose the ***.img*** file of a local Raspbian image

**Set the Target: Choose the Compute Module which will appear as a mass storage device**

Compute Module now appears as a mass storage device to select as a flashing target. Select it and choose "***Continue***":
[image: Compute Module shows as a Mass Storage Device]

Click "***Flash***"
[image: Choose Compute Module]

Voila.  Raspbian is now installed on your Compute Module's eMMC storage.  Remove the MicroUSB cable from the "***USB Slave***" port and the compute module can now be booted via the ***Compute Module IO Board*** by just inserting the power cable into it into the Micros USB "***Power In***" port.

Note that whatever the size of your eMMC storage- 8/16/24/32 GB - the file system will be expanded automatically to the maximum extent possible.

Comment: Thank you a ton for posting this. The primary method, as pointed to by Raspberry Pi Foundation, didn't seem to be working for me. Your method using balenaEtcher worked great! 

One important note: I don't think you mention above that a developer needs to power up the dev board in order for balenaEtcher to recognize it. So, in order for this method to work for me, I had to power up the dev board via the J2 micro USB, then also plug in my computer to micro USB slave.

Comment: My example uses USB-C which powers the board, but yes, I shouldn't take this as the common configuration; USB-C is still not widely enough adopted.  So per your feedback I added a note stating if "not" using USB-C for the user to connect IO board to the mains with the power lead.  Thanks for your feedback- very much appreciated!

Comment: . yeap, that would make sense about usb-c

Comment: @risingtiger Please accept the answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only accepting an answer will finish the question and it will not pop up again and again for years.

Comment: I tried your "method 2" and it failed: My compute module was not recognized. I had to follow the original method and got a disk after "rpiboot", so maybe that's something the needs to be done only once.

Comment: @user242579 I'll need to see if I can reproduce your issue when I get a moment and will update the answer accordingly if something has changed since I posted it. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: It'll be difficult to reproduce because I think it is a one-time thing that the RPI procedure does to allow your shorter procedure to work. It's possible that I had a "first week-of-issue", "never used before" CM3 here...  (and that they put them through the steps in the factory nowadays).

Comment: It seems that Balena, turns the CM3 into a flash drive in the background. No messages in the GUI. This takes 20 sec. I might have run balena without sufficient rights to do that the first time around.