# How do I boot a Compute Module 3+ Lite?

Tags: boot, compute-module-3, compute-module-development-kit

I bought a Raspberry Pi "[Compute Module 3+ Development Kit](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/processor-microcontroller-development-kits/1829894/?relevancy-data=636F3D3126696E3D4931384E53656172636847656E65726963266C753D656E266D6D3D6D61746368616C6C7061727469616C26706D3D5E2E2A2426706F3D31333326736E3D592673723D2673743D43415443485F414C4C5F44454641554C542673633D592677633D4E4F4E45267573743D52617370626572727920506920436F6D70757465204D6F64756C6520332B20446576204B6974267374613D52617370626572727920506920436F6D70757465204D6F64756C65203320446576204B697426&searchHistory=%7B%22enabled%22%3Atrue%7D)" which includes a Compute Module 3+ Lite (CM3l).  Unlike the standard Compute Module 3+ that's included in the kit, this has no on-board eMMC storage to flash a bootable image to.

There's an SD card slot on the Compute Module IO board, but despite inserting an imaged card with Raspbian into it and powering it on, it still doesn't boot?!?!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The instructions that ship with the kit are a bit opaque for the Compute Module 3+ Dev Kit.  I gleaned enough however from them to arrive at the following solution to boot a CM3+ ***Lite*** using an SD card I imaged using [Balena Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) (highly recommended for imaging SD cards for either standard Pi's or the Pi Compute Module's with eMMC onboard memory).

First, as there's (2) compute Modules in the kit, let's identify the CM 3+ ***Lite*** (the one with no eMMC on-board storage) so there's no confusion:

[image: CM3+ Lite identification]

The kit ships with 4x pairs of jumper wires.  We will use one of these to enable the Compute Module 3+ ***Lite*** to see the storage on the IO board that it's plugged into.

Next picture is with the Compute Module 3+ ***Lite*** inserted into the Compute Module IO board with an imaged SD card in the IO board's SD slot. Connecting the jumper wire to the 2nd pair of pins in GPIO ***Bank 0*** enable the Compute Module 3 ***Lite*** to boot from the SD card on the IO board when micro USB power lead is connected to the "***Power In***" micro USB socket:

[image: GPIO pins to enable SD card visibility connected to jumper wires]

I achieved a correct result from the above procedure, but if there's any observed imperfections please advise and I'll update it.

If you need help imaging the Compute Module 3+ with eMMC on-board storage that ships with your kit, please follow these instructions which are quick, painless and proven to work:

[How do I Flash (install) Raspbian on Raspberry Pi Compute Module 3 / 3+?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96032/how-do-i-flash-install-raspbian-on-raspberry-pi-compute-module-3-3)

Hope this gets folks up and running with their new Compute Module 3+ Dev Kits which just started shipping yesterday-